# How to Prevent Bubbling For Form Submit

Tags: javascript, preventdefault, event-bubbling

I have form that calls the function GenerateWords when it is submitted and returns false.

```
<form id="3Form" onsubmit="GenerateWords(this); return false;">
```

This is causing problems with Google Tag Manager implementation as it does not bubble up to the form submit listener.

I understand event.preventDefault(); needs to be used and return false removed but don't know how to implement this. The current javascript I have is:

```
function GenerateWords(F) {
var strWords = F.words.value;
if ... condition is false
    return false;
}
if ... condition is false
    return false;
}
vars declared
for (var i = 0; i < ctLines; i++) {
    var strLine = arrLines[i];
    strLine = Trim(strLine.replace(/[\r]/g,""));
    if successful condition
    }
}
F.result.value = oResult.join("");
F.result.focus();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this in javascript:

```
 function GenerateWords(F,ev) {  // event object 
    ...
    if(someCondition)  // condition when the form should not be submitted.
    ev.preventDefault();
    }
```

and you may remove `return false;` from the form tag and pass the event reference

```
<form id="3Form" onsubmit="GenerateWords(this,event);">
```

Comment: Here's an explanation for why not to use 'return false'. http://www.simoahava.com/analytics/dont-gtm-listeners-work/. It's using GTM, but the gist is the same.