# How to open another tab on click without refresh current page in ASP.NET Web Forms?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, page-refresh

I want to be able to click on a button which opens another tab on click. In my case this is done using two `ASP.Net` controls, one `asp literal` with `<form>` tags to format it as a submit button, because I need it to have some `POST` functionality. The code inside the `asp literal` looks like the following:

```
<input type='submit' id='openWindowButton' value = 'Open window'>
```

with a given `URL` and `_blank` to open the new tab.
I am using another asp control, a `LinkButton` this time, to run an event on click, and also to trigger the click on the submit `asp literal` with `javascript` code. It looks like this:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="literalID" OnClick="DoStuff" runat="server">Do stuff</asp:LinkButton>
```

On `DoStuff` event I need to run some code, which populates the `asp literal` with the code mentioned above, and after it finishes, it triggers click on the submit button with `openWindowButton` ID like this:

```
function InvokeReportFormClick() {
            document.getElementById("openWindowButton").click();
            return false;
        }
```

The code for click is added with `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` method.

Everything works fine this way, the LinkButton populates the literal and then clicks on it, and the literal opens a tab. The only problem is that the page is reloaded, and I want to avoid this behavior. 
I have tried the return false at the end of the script, but if I only return false from the javascript method, as can be seen above, the page still reloads, and I think it is because of the generated click on the `asp literal`.

I could add I add return false on the onclick event on the `asp literal` input as follows:

```
<input type='submit' id='openWindowButton' value = 'Open window' onclick="return false;">
```

but it stops from opening the tab I need.

I have also tried to put the `asp:Linkbutton` in an `UpdatePanel` control as in this sample:

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="reportScriptManager">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanelID" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>

<asp:LinkButton ID="literalID" OnClick="DoStuff" runat="server">Do stuff</asp:LinkButton>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

But it still refresh the page, as I still guess from the `asp literal` click. And if I add the asp literal next to `LinkButton`, the page does not refresh, but I get an error saying that

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null.

Which I guess it happens because the page does not reload, and the `asp literal` Text is not loaded in page when click action occurs.

How can I stop the reload of the page, and still maintain the same functionality of these buttons?
Best regards!

**EDIT**

I have remarked that the button of submit made from `asp literal` does not reload the form, as a simple manual click on it only opens the new tab. So the main problem in this case is only to make the asp `LinkButton` not trigger the page reload.

In the .cs file I am using this method to register my script to be runned after click on the LinkButton, as is suggested on [asp.net forum](http://forums.asp.net/t/1540843.aspx?How+Do+I+run+OnClick+in+serve+side+before+running+OnClientClick+in+client+side+):

`RegisterStartupScript(Page page, Type type, string key, string script, bool addScriptTags)`

Comment: I think this problem is because you're letting the event bubble up - see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25092840/how-to-prevent-bubbling-for-form-submit

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham thank you for reply, I have tried to use prevent defaults for both buttons, but didn't worked, the page still reloads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was fixed after I realized that I am using the wrong overload of the `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript`. I was using the method which takes the Page as first parameter (it can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310408(v=vs.110).aspx)), and after I tried to use the method which takes as parameter

> The control that is registering the client script block

as in msdn documentation, and sent as control the LinkButton, it actually worked. The page was not reloading anymore. I hope this can help somebody with the same problem.